# Javafx how to override a LIstView's listener

Tags: listview, javafx, overriding, listener

I have a JavaFX app with a ListView:

```
    ...
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] fruitArr = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "peach", "grapes", "watermelon", "kiwi"};
    arrList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fruitArr));
    ObservableList<String> obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arrList);

    myListView.setItems(obList);
    myListView
        .getSelectionModel()
        .selectedIndexProperty()
        .addListener(
            (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> displaySelection(newVal));
    ...

...later...
private void displaySelection(Number newVal) {
    textA.setText("Your Selection Is: "+arrList.get((int) newVal));
}
```

I also have a button which randomly selects an item on behalf of the user:

```
    btnPickSomething.setOnAction(event -> {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String randomlyPicked = arrList.get(rand.nextInt(arrList.size()));
        textA.setText("Your Selection Is: "+randomlyPicked);
    });
```

This is all fairly simple JavaFX 101-type stuff.  Here's what I can't figure out:  Suppose I click "orange" in the ListView and then get indecisive and want the button to make the decision for me.  I click the button and it randomly selects "banana".  The app looks like this:

[image: My Fruit App - Button selects one thing, ListView not sync'ed]

The textA field is displaying the button's randomly-selected String... but the ListView is still showing "orange" selected.  Of course, this is what the code is supposed to do... but I want a solution where the ListView selection matches what the button selected.  The correct view should be this:

[image: My Fruit App - Button and ListView are sync'ed]

Its a subtle thing, but important for reasons beyond the scope of this post.  But there MUST be a way to code the button to essentially use (override?) the ListView in the same way the user does, i.e., when you click the button, the randomly-selected item is highlighted in the ListView.  How can I recode the button to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't have quite enough time to write up a proper answer, Ill let someone else do that. Basically its `myListView.getSelectionModel().select(randomlyPicked);` In your buttons `setOnAction`

Comment: @HypnicJerk Yes!  Yes, that works beautifully.  I've seen that command before, but never understood how to apply it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `selectionModel` of `ListView` to manipulate the selection. This can be done by passing the item or it's index:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.nextInt(arrList.size());

myListView.getSelectionModel().select(index);
```

You could also replace the last line with

```
String item = myListView.getItems().get(index);
myListView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
```

but in this case you always select the first one of duplicate `ListView` items.

Comment: You can remove the `textA.setText(...)` line too, because the listener on the list view's selection model will still be triggered.

Comment: @James_D  Yeah, fabian's solution makes that line redundant.  This is exactly what I was hoping for.  :)